# How Can I improve the Pressure in my Shower When it's Fine in my Bath

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure

I have a shower that connects from my bath - there's the tap for my bath and then there's a little metal rod that I lift up to redirect water pressure to my shower head. The water pressure is fine in the bath and everywhere else in our apartment however the shower head gets little to no pressure.

When I remove the shower head from its holder and hold it closer to my bath the pressure increases as it seems to be a gravity based system so the water just has trouble getting up the shower hose. We have replaced the shower head and hose with no real results so I was hoping that there is something I can do to improve the water pressure without installing a pump in the pipes as we only rent this apartment.

This issue only affects the hot water going into the shower.

As I mentioned, when I hold the shower head lower to the bath, the pressure of the hot water increases, but the cold is consistently good. It does not appear to be a flow restrictor or anti-scald device, just a problem with the water not actually being able to make it up the hose when the shower head is up high.

Comment: Pressure in a building water should be close to equal at all points.  The only time to have reduced pressure is when another tap/faucet is open also.  If pressure is reduced in one faucet, then the problem is usually with the taps or a partial blockage in the pipe for that faucet.  Sounds like a job for the landlords maintenance people.

Comment: Most of those combination shower head and hoses have built in flow restrictors. Check to see if you've got them and can remove them. Sometimes, the hose is just too small.

Comment: Tub fillers will flow as much water as possible to fill the tub promptly. Showers often have flow reducers to limit the amount of water to a specific rate, e.g. 2.5 gallons per minute maximum to reduce the water (and energy) consumption.

Comment: Yep, probably a flow restrictor  .  Had one in a previous home after the bathroom was remodeled. It was awful.   I took it apart ,found the restrictor and drilled a larger hole in it. Problem solved!

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's a water restrictor. However, I could be wrong. The hot and cold water are mixed together and then sent down the shower hose, so surely if it was a flow restrictor, it would affect the cold water, which it does not. Also, as I mentioned, when I hold my shower head down lower at the bath there is actually an increase in pressure from the hot water as it doesn't have to travel up.

Comment: @PaulGeoghegan if this only affects hot water your question should say that in the question. It's likely som esort of scald prevention device causing the problem, but what you need to do is call building maintenance.

Comment: Does it flow ok with no shower head?

Comment: where do you get the hot water from ?

Comment: My diverter is a knob on the wall that turns, instead of the pull up knob you have on your tub spout. Having just replaced washers in it, I know that it's possible that there could have been some blockage that would have prevented it from turning all the way. It's possible that this may have allowed more cold into the shower head than hot. It's possible that your diverter knob is blocked in some way and that's causing the issue. You'd have to disassemble it to look, but I'm not sure how you'd go about that.

Comment: So I checked and the same thing happens without the showerhead. The hot water comes from a tank in the next room over and it doesn't seem to be the diverter. But I'm unsure.

Comment: Guess you could test your hypothesis that it's a pressure problem by connecting a hose to a sink faucet and holding it "up high"?  Maybe the shower faucet cartridge is messed up?  Did you ever figure this out?